# Hide Copyright Bing Map Ajax Control 7.0

Tags: jquery, html, bing-maps

How to remove Copyright in [Bing Map Ajax Control 7.0](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMap1)  ?

[image]

There isn't any option to do this.
I tried remove element from DOM by jQuery but is not working.

There is any way to remove this?

Comment: You're not allowed to. Why would you want to?
You could always overlay it with a black div with z-index:1000

Comment: I using a very small map and this copyright hide a lot of map area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use tricky CSS tips to hide copyrights on the control and it's not recommended nor the official way. In order to hide the copyright on the AJAX v7.0 control, you can use the property on the mapOption's property called showCopyright, see the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx

**Important:**

> Bing Maps Platform API Terms of Use requires copyright information to
>   be displayed. Only set this option to false when copyright information
>   is displayed through alternate means.

In conbination, you can use the copyrightchanged on the Map element so you can track and manage the copyright in your own way.

**Code example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        function getMap() {

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('myMap'), 
                { 
                    credentials: 'YOURKEY', 
                    showCopyright: false
                });

            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'copyrightchanged', function() {
                map.getCopyrights(function(result) {
                    var container = document.getElementById('copyright');
                    container.innerHTML = result.join(' ');
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="myMap" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
    <div id="copyright"></div>
</body>
</html>
```